# Comparing variables in awk

Tags: awk

My file has timestamps in its 6th field which looks like this: **Mon Jul 7 14:53:16 PDT 2014**

I want to get all those lines from this file whose 6th field **values are within the last 24 hours**.

**Sample Input:**

```
abc -> /aa/bbb, hello, /home/user/blah.pl, 516, usc, Mon Jul 4 10:06:33 PDT 2014
abc -> /aa/bbb, hello, /home/user/blah.pl, 516, usc, Mon Jul 5 10:06:33 PDT 2014
abc -> /aa/bbb, hello, /home/user/blah.pl, 516, usc, Mon Jul 7 07:06:33 PDT 2014 
abc -> /aa/bbb, hello, /home/user/blah.pl, 516, usc, Mon Jul 7 08:06:33 PDT 2014
abc -> /aa/bbb, hello, /home/user/blah.pl, 516, usc, Mon Jul 7 09:06:33 PDT 2014
abc -> /aa/bbb, hello, /home/user/blah.pl, 516, usc, Mon Jul 7 10:06:33 PDT 2014
```

The field delimiter is comma.

**Sample Code**
But it's not working as expected:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS = ","};
{ a=$6;
aint=a +"%y%m%d%H%M%S";
yestint=$(date --date='1 day ago' +"%y%m%d%H%M%S");
if (aint>yestint)
print aint;
}' /location/canzee/textfile.txt
```

**Sample Output**
I get an output like this:

```
awk: cmd. line:4: yestint=$(date --date=1
awk: cmd. line:4:                      ^ syntax error
awk: cmd. line:5: (END OF FILE)
awk: cmd. line:5: syntax error
```

**Desired Output**

```
Mon Jul 7 07:06:33 PDT 2014
Mon Jul 7 08:06:33 PDT 2014
Mon Jul 7 09:06:33 PDT 2014
Mon Jul 7 10:06:33 PDT 2014
```

I would like to know how to go about this if I can't call shell commands like date within awk command. I hope its clear enough.

Comment: `$(yest)` should be `"$yest"`. What is the format of field 6 in the file? `$yest` will be something like `Sun Jul  6 16:26:09 CDT 2014`, I don't know how you expect to compare that with `<`.

Comment: `awk -v yest=$yest...`

Comment: Your variable-reference syntax is off: Use `"$yest"` or `"${yest}"` - `$(yest)` is not a variable reference, but a _command substitution_.

Comment: Do you think it has to do with the format of the time stamp? Can you show a sample line from the file?

Comment: add a debug line that shows both values, surrounded by boundary characters, for example, `print "a=|"a"|\tyest=|"yest"|"`. The other comments are also to be observed ;-)  Good luck.

Comment: What is the format of the timestamps in the 6th column of your file?

Comment: Format of timestamp in 6th field is Mon Jul 7 14:27:56 PDT 2014

Comment: You should convert the timestamp to unix epoch when comparing.

Comment: Unless the date formats are in some variation of the ISO 8601 standard notation (2014-07-07 14:36:36 or similar), you can't compare them reliably using `awk` without (possibly extensive) processing.  Note that `date +'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` produces that format.  You can add a `T` between the date and time components to ensure you have a single field containing both components.

Comment: awk is not shell. awk is a tool you can call from shell to process text. You can't call shell programs like date directly from awk just like you can't call them directly from C. Post some sample input and expected output and explain what it is you want to do.

Comment: @EdMorton I ve edited my Question to show sample code and output. I hope its clear now.

Comment: No, I didn't ask for code, I asked for sample input and expected output. Show, say 5 lines of input, and the output you want given that input.

Comment: @EdMorton There is no input for my script, I just run it and its supposed to return the 6th field from that file which is within the last 24 hours.

Comment: "that file" IS your input. Show a few lines of "that file", and what you want the output to be given some specific value for the current date/time.

Comment: @EdMorton A sample line from that file would be abc -> /aa/bbb/ccc/ddd, hello, /home/user/ol/gyu/ip/bin/blah.pl, 516, usermc, Mon Jul  7 10:06:33 PDT 2014           The field delimiter is comma.

Comment: Please listen to what I'm saying: update your question to show A FEW LINES of "that file" along with the output you want given that input and some specific current date/time. you are making it much harder than it has to be for us to help you.

Comment: Thank you for posting that. Now we can see that your fields are NOT separated by commas but instead by commas surrounded by spaces. Whatever script you try, the field separator (FS) should be `[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*`, not simply `,`. Now, do you have GNU awk (gawk) or not? `awk --version` will tell you.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes, I do.  awk --version
GNU Awk 3.1.3
Copyright (C) 1989, 1991-2003 Free Software Foundation.

Comment: Good, then you have time functions available and @oogas answer should get you very close to what you want after he updates the FS value. Having said that, that is a VERY old version of gawk, you should install a new one if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sketch of an idea. Beware that it is gawk-specific.

```
# An array to convert abbreviated month names to numbers.
BEGIN {m["Jan"]=1; m["Feb"]=2; m["Mar"]=3; m["Apr"]=4; m["May"]=5; m["Jun"]=6
       m["Jul"]=7; m["Aug"]=8; m["Sep"]=9; m["Oct"]=10; m["Nov"]=11; m["Dec"]=12;}


# later in your script
{

# systime() gives the number of seconds since the "epoch".
# Subtract 24-hours-worth of seconds from it to get "yesterday".
# (Note that this is yesterday at a specific time, which may not
# really be what you want.)
yest = systime() - 24 * 60 * 60;

a = "Mon Jul 7 14:27:56 PDT 2014"   # or however a gets its value

# Split the fields of a into the array f (splitting on spaces).
split(a, f, " ");

# Split the fields of f[4] (the time) into the array t (splitting on colons).
split(f[4], t, ":")

# mktime() converts a date specification into seconds since the epoch.
# The datespec format is: 2014 7 7 14 27 56 [optional dst flag]
# If the daylight savings time flag is left out the system tries to determine
# whether or not dst is in effect.
tm = mktime(f[6] " " m[f[2]] " " f[3] " " t[1] " " t[2] " " t[3])

#Compare the seconds since epochs.
if (tm > yest)
  ...

}
```

In the context of your program, it might be done like this:

```
awk '
  BEGIN {
    m["Jan"]=1; m["Feb"]=2; m["Mar"]=3; m["Apr"]=4; m["May"]=5; m["Jun"]=6
    m["Jul"]=7; m["Aug"]=8; m["Sep"]=9; m["Oct"]=10; m["Nov"]=11; m["Dec"]=12;
    FS = "[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*"
    yest = systime() - 24 * 60 * 60;
  }

  {
    split($6, f, " ")
    split(f[4], t, ":")
    tm = mktime(f[6] " " m[f[2]] " " f[3] " " t[1] " " t[2] " " t[3])
    if (tm > yest)
      print $6;
  }
' /location/canzee/textfile.txt
```

Comment: You should mention that your script is gawk-specific. The OP may not be using GNU awk.

Comment: @EdMorton I have a hard time knowing what is gawk-specific or not. Is it the time functions? And is there a table someplace where I can look that kind of thing up?

Comment: Yes. time functions (mktime()/systime()), gensub(), PROCINFO[], asort/asorti(), and true-multi-dimensional arrays (arr[i][j] syntax vs arr[i,j]) are the typical gawk-specific features people use. I'm not aware of a table anywhere that's kept up to date.

Comment: FYI, an alternative way to map the month name to a number is to look up the name in a string of months, e.g. `awk 'BEGIN{print (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec","Jun")+2)/3}'` -> `6`. Its just a bit briefer than populating an array to explicitly map the names to numbers.

Comment: @EdMorton I like that! Much less typing. I'll leave it as is, but I'd remember that for the future. Thanks.

Comment: @EdMorton Here is another way to convert month to number: `awk 'BEGIN {split("Jan Feb Mar Apr Mai Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec",s," ");for (i in s) m[s[i]]=i;print m["Jun"]}' -> 6`. Yours may be shorter, but this may be better if you have to use it many times in the `awk`

Comment: @Jotne that is another valid approach but better how? If it's to avoid duplication `awk 'function m(n) {return (match("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",n)+2)/3} BEGIN{print m("Jun")}'` would be briefest and easiest to add checks to to handle invalid month names in one place. Maybe there's a performance difference? idk...

Comment: @EdMorton Did forget about the `function` :)